# Session get null After login immediately in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

On login I am just assigning values to session but after login it becomes null. I set the session timeout as well but still it doesn't work.

```
   public ActionResult Login([Bind(Include = "Username, Password")] LoginModel loginModel, string ReturnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Egov_Users eGov_Users = db.Egov_Users
                .Where(p => p.UserType.Type != "O" && p.UserName == loginModel.Username)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (eGov_Users == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username");
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                if (eGov_Users.Password != loginModel.Password)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Password");
                    return View();
                }

                var loginDetail = new LoginDetails();

                loginDetail.supplierID = (eGov_Users.SupplierID != null) ? eGov_Users.SupplierID.Value : 0;
                loginDetail.userID = eGov_Users.UserId;
                loginDetail.username = eGov_Users.UserName;
                loginDetail.firstName = eGov_Users.FirstName;
                loginDetail.lastName = eGov_Users.LastName;

                Session["UserID"] = loginDetail.userID;
                Session["SupplierID"] = loginDetail.supplierID;
                Session["Username"] = loginDetail.username;
                Session["DisplayName"] = loginDetail.firstName + " " + loginDetail.lastName;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ReturnUrl))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Users");
                }
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Login");
    }
```

In webconfig I have set the session timeout as well.

Comment: Have you stepped through your code to see if your `LoginDetails()` object actually contain any values?

Comment: Is your returnurl empty?

Comment: Will you please specify how much time you set for session timeout?